# Issues with PyCharm and 'Run manage.py task...' in a Django project

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm to write the code of a Django project I'm developing.

My project's name is `A`, and I have created (manually) an application under it called `B`, so it looks like:

```
+--A 
|---B
|---...
```

The problem is the following:

When I go to *Tools > Run manage.py task...*, and select, for example, `sqlall`, it says:

> Please, select application

and doesn't show `B`.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't it be calling the `manage.py` file inside `A` directory instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 1.0\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py`?

**Important Edit:**

That project wasn't created using PyCharm. I just loaded the folder with PyCharm because I created it some days ago using the python shell. Now I created a Django project using File > New Project and it seems to work. Any idea of how to make it work with an already existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have the answer to this question.

The problem was that I had `A` instead of `B.A` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in `settings.py` file.